# Where do you set node revision permissions?

Tags: 7

I’m using Drupal 7. I created a Content Type called ItemRequests.
One of the fields is a Body field.
As my authenticated users keep editing this Body field at different times, I want them to be able to see the full Body field revision history.
I went to the Content **Type —> Edit**, and made sure **Create new revision** was checked. However, when I edit an ItemRequest node, it says I (the administrator) do not have permission to view revisions? Where do I set up permissions for node revisions?
My users want to view the editing history for these nodes.

Comment: For that you need https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning and I think you also need to enable revisions per content type.